# Seed database with foreign key - seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, seeding, faker

I'm trying to seed database with Faker gem and I am succeeding when I am trying to seed just movies, but when I try to seed movies with each having 1-10 comments I'm getting bunch of different errors depends what I change.

Here is how my seeds.rb looks like:

```
require 'faker'

formats = %w[Beta VHS IMAX HD SuperHD 4K DVD BluRay]
genres = %w[Triller Comedy Horror Action Drama SciFi Documentary]
images = %w[magento.svg mysql.svg php.svg jquery.svg mongodb.svg prestashop.svg meteor.svg]

Movie.destroy_all
Comment.destroy_all

100.times do
  movie = Movie.create([{ name: Faker::Book.title,
                          director: Faker::Name.name,
                          description: Faker::FamilyGuy.quote,
                          year: rand(1920..2018),
                          length: rand(80..240),
                          format: formats[rand(formats.length)],
                          genre: genres[rand(genres.length)],
                          image: images[rand(images.length)],
                          thumbnail: images[rand(images.length)] }])
  unless movie.nil?
    rand(1..10).times do
      movie.comments.create(
        author: Faker::Name.name,
        title: Faker::Book.title,
        content: Faker::FamilyGuy.quote,
        rating: rand(1..5)
      )
    end
  end
  puts movie.inspect
end
```

Here is my comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

And here is my movie model:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments

  validates_presence_of :name, :director
#  validates_numericality_of :year, :length, greater_than: 0
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, message: 'Name is already used!'
#  validates_length_of :year, maximum: 4

  paginates_per 10

  def proper_name
    name.titleize
  end

end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems:

1. In `Movie.create`, you need to remove the square brackets. That's because the ActiveRecord `create` method needs a Hash, not an Array. While you're at it, you can remove the curly braces as well, and your arguments will still be recognized as a Hash.
2. Checking to see if `movie` is `nil` is not the right test, as `movie` will always exist, even if it wasn't saved to the database. Change your test from `unless movie.nil?` to `if movie.persisted?` This will avoid an error caused by trying to save comments to a movie that isn't saved to the database.

So your code should look like this:

```
100.times do
  movie = Movie.create(name: Faker::Book.title,
                       director: Faker::Name.name,
                       description: Faker::FamilyGuy.quote,
                       year: rand(1920..2018),
                       length: rand(80..240),
                       format: formats[rand(formats.length)],
                       genre: genres[rand(genres.length)],
                       image: images[rand(images.length)],
                       thumbnail: images[rand(images.length)])
  if movie.persisted?
    rand(1..10).times do
      movie.comments.create(
          author: Faker::Name.name,
          title: Faker::Book.title,
          content: Faker::FamilyGuy.quote,
          rating: rand(1..5)
      )
    end
  end
  puts movie.inspect
end
```

Why weren't some movies being saved? I suspect you were running out of movie titles and then failing your uniqueness constraint. Faker has a finite number of responses for any category. I think there are only 22 unique `Faker::Book.title` responses.

Comment: It worked instantly, i just had to remove validations for uniqueness. Thanks for help and fast response